# Term for turning "Florida" into "Flo Rida"

Tags: single-word-requests, portmanteau-words

What would be the name for dissecting a word to create a phrase — the opposite of a portmanteau? Like the rapper Flo Rida made his name out of Florida. Is there a term for that?

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I can think of is [*word play*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_play).

> Word play or wordplay is a literary technique in which the words that are used become the main subject of the work, ..., and telling character names are common examples of word play.

It looks like an [eggcorn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn), but Flo Rida doesn't mean the same thing as Florida.

It's almost an [anagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anagram) but the letters haven't been rearranged so much as moved apart a bit.

It is an [Aptronym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym) (well, if you think Flo Rida is good at what he does.)

> An aptronym is a name aptly suited to its owner.

Answer (score 0):

The example cited is a [homonym](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/homonym) : Florida (a city) and Flo Rida ( a person's name)

Comment: They're not pronounced the same, though. "Flo Rida" is pronounced "Flow Rye-da".

Comment: Oh. I didn't know that. In that case, its probably a homograph[link]{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph}

Comment: They're not written the same, either. The space matters...

Comment: But the written forms aren't the same.

Comment: neologistic toponym? toponymic neologism?